# Apple Store We were unable to review your app as it crashed on launch

Tags: ios, xamarin

My Xamarin iOS App, Works great in the simulator, but when i publish to the apple store i get this error:

Guideline 2.1 - Performance - App Completeness

We were unable to review your app as it crashed on launch. We have attached detailed crash logs to help troubleshoot this issue.

Heres the error log:

```
{"app_name":"ProyectoAngela.Prism.iOS","timestamp":"2022-01-14 10:33:37.00 -0800","app_version":"1.3","slice_uuid":"0725ebef-24d0-3dd4-aba2-bd0283b254a8","adam_id":"1604093951","build_version":"1.3","platform":2,"bundleID":"com.mxxx.xxxx","share_with_app_devs":0,"is_first_party":0,"bug_type":"309","os_version":"iPhone OS 15.2 (19C56)","incident_id":"C23408FA-A088-4955-9454-2BD6CA8A371E","name":"ProyectoAngela.Prism.iOS"}
{
  "uptime" : 2400000,
  "procLaunch" : "2022-01-14 10:33:34.8287 -0800",
  "procRole" : "Foreground",
  "version" : 2,
  "userID" : 501,
  "deployVersion" : 210,
  "modelCode" : "iPad7,5",
  "procStartAbsTime" : 59878077029641,
  "coalitionID" : 5657,
  "osVersion" : {
    "isEmbedded" : true,
    "train" : "iPhone OS 15.2",
    "releaseType" : "User",
    "build" : "19C56"
  },
  "captureTime" : "2022-01-14 10:33:36.5764 -0800",
  "incident" : "C23408FA-A088-4955-9454-2BD6CA8A371E",
  "bug_type" : "309",
  "pid" : 24812,
  "procExitAbsTime" : 59878118842372,
  "cpuType" : "ARM-64",
  "procName" : "ProyectoAngela.Prism.iOS",
  "procPath" : "\/private\/var\/containers\/Bundle\/Application\/3F629218-B618-43E2-A456-6AF0F4B6132B\/ProyectoAngela.Prism.iOS.app\/ProyectoAngela.Prism.iOS",
  "bundleInfo" : {"CFBundleShortVersionString":"1.3","CFBundleVersion":"1.3","CFBundleIdentifier":"com.mxxx.xxxx","DTAppStoreToolsBuild":"13C90b"},
  "storeInfo" : {"itemID":"1604093951","deviceIdentifierForVendor":"F13E8B85-5D9C-4C8E-885D-4550BE2D0EB1","thirdParty":true,"softwareVersionExternalIdentifier":"43806246"},
  "parentProc" : "launchd",
  "parentPid" : 1,
  "coalitionName" : "com.mxxx.xxxx",
  "crashReporterKey" : "36c14055bb17c6d0db3f456869338332b769d45e",
  "isCorpse" : 1,
  "exception" : {"codes":"0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000","rawCodes":[0,0],"type":"EXC_CRASH","signal":"SIGABRT"},
  "ktriageinfo" : "VM - Fault hit memory shortage\nVM - Fault hit memory shortage\nVM - Fault hit memory shortage\nVM - Fault hit memory shortage\n",
  "asi" : {"libsystem_c.dylib":["abort() called"]},
  "lastExceptionBacktrace" : [{"imageOffset":597308,"symbol":"__exceptionPreprocess","symbolLocation":216,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":83624,"symbol":"objc_exception_throw","symbolLocation":56,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":1190300,"symbol":"_userInfoForFileAndLine","symbolLocation":0,"imageIndex":12},{"imageOffset":5034496,"symbol":"-[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:]","symbolLocation":2028,"imageIndex":10},{"imageOffset":3381572,"symbol":"-[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer completeApplicationLaunchWithFBSScene:transitionContext:]","symbolLocation":148,"imageIndex":10},{"imageOffset":1694148,"symbol":"_UIScenePerformActionsWithLifecycleActionMask","symbolLocation":96,"imageIndex":10},{"imageOffset":2890720,"symbol":"__101-[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer _evalTransitionToSettings:fromSettings:forceExit:withTransitionStore:]_block_invoke","symbolLocation":196,"imageIndex":10},{"imageOffset":4031172,"symbol":"-[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer _performBlock:withApplicationOfDeactivationReasons:fromReasons:]","symbolLocation":240,"imageIndex":10},{"imageOffset":6307680,"symbol":"-[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer _evalTransitionToSettings:fromSettings:forceExit:withTransitionStore:]","symbolLocation":732,"imageIndex":10},{"imageOffset":5847968,"symbol":"-[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer uiScene:transitionedFromState:withTransitionContext:]","symbolLocation":336,"imageIndex":10},{"imageOffset":1697964,"symbol":"__186-[_UIWindowSceneFBSSceneTransitionContextDrivenLifecycleSettingsDiffAction _performActionsForUIScene:withUpdatedFBSScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:lifecycleActionType:]_block_invoke","symbolLocation":188,"imageIndex":10},{"imageOffset":2468940,"symbol":"+[BSAnimationSettings(UIKit) tryAnimatingWithSettings:actions:completion:]","symbolLocation":812,"imageIndex":10},{"imageOffset":1705532,"symbol":"_UISceneSettingsDiffActionPerformChangesWithTransitionContext","symbolLocation":248,"imageIndex":10},{"imageOffset":2645692,"symbol":"-[_UIWindowSceneFBSSceneTransitionContextDrivenLifecycleSettingsDiffAction _performActionsForUIScene:withUpdatedFBSScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:lifecycleActionType:]","symbolLocation":356,"imageIndex":10},{"imageOffset":7212472,"symbol":"__64-[UIScene scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke.576","symbolLocation":772,"imageIndex":10},{"imageOffset":1894672,"symbol":"-[UIScene _emitSceneSettingsUpdateResponseForCompletion:afterSceneUpdateWork:]","symbolLocation":248,"imageIndex":10},{"imageOffset":2164592,"symbol":"-[UIScene scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:]","symbolLocation":264,"imageIndex":10},{"imageOffset":3400924,"symbol":"-[UIApplication workspace:didCreateScene:withTransitionContext:completion:]","symbolLocation":548,"imageIndex":10},{"imageOffset":2638552,"symbol":"-[UIApplicationSceneClientAgent scene:didInitializeWithEvent:completion:]","symbolLocation":360,"imageIndex":10},{"imageOffset":158380,"symbol":"-[FBSScene _callOutQueue_agent_didCreateWithTransitionContext:completion:]","symbolLocation":412,"imageIndex":8},{"imageOffset":299212,"symbol":"__94-[FBSWorkspaceScenesClient createWithSceneID:groupID:parameters:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke.180","symbolLocation":100,"imageIndex":8},{"imageOffset":37104,"symbol":"-[FBSWorkspace _calloutQueue_executeCalloutFromSource:withBlock:]","symbolLocation":232,"imageIndex":8},{"imageOffset":42232,"symbol":"__94-[FBSWorkspaceScenesClient createWithSceneID:groupID:parameters:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke","symbolLocation":312,"imageIndex":8},{"imageOffset":410024,"symbol":"_dispatch_client_callout","symbolLocation":16,"imageIndex":7},{"imageOffset":27344,"symbol":"_dispatch_block_invoke_direct$VARIANT$mp","symbolLocation":220,"imageIndex":7},{"imageOffset":42960,"symbol":"__FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__","symbolLocation":40,"imageIndex":8},{"imageOffset":40156,"symbol":"-[FBSSerialQueue _targetQueue_performNextIfPossible]","symbolLocation":176,"imageIndex":8},{"imageOffset":56900,"symbol":"-[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource]","symbolLocation":24,"imageIndex":8},{"imageOffset":729776,"symbol":"__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__","symbolLocation":24,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":795352,"symbol":"__CFRunLoopDoSource0","symbolLocation":204,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":22136,"symbol":"__CFRunLoopDoSources0","symbolLocation":256,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":43688,"symbol":"__CFRunLoopRun","symbolLocation":768,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":122396,"symbol":"CFRunLoopRunSpecific","symbolLocation":572,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":6560,"symbol":"GSEventRunModal","symbolLocation":160,"imageIndex":9},{"imageOffset":5162496,"symbol":"-[UIApplication _run]","symbolLocation":1080,"imageIndex":10},{"imageOffset":2628360,"symbol":"UIApplicationMain","symbolLocation":2028,"imageIndex":10},{"imageOffset":6357064,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":5659504,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":735588,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":4497056,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":27583448,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":28347188,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":28372456,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":27445224,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":29268332,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":735424,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":98896,"symbol":"start","symbolLocation":444,"imageIndex":11}],
  "faultingThread" : 0,
  "threads" : [{"triggered":true,"id":7001002,"threadState":{"x":[{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":10000000},{"value":6656},{"value":0},{"value":4377052544,"symbolLocation":0,"symbol":"_main_thread"},{"value":9444832902787961409},{"value":1000},{"value":0},{"value":4374720048},{"value":4396135443},{"value":96},{"value":2147483648},{"value":328},{"value":35220},{"value":0},{"value":6},{"value":259},{"value":4377052768,"symbolLocation":224,"symbol":"_main_thread"},{"value":0},{"value":4387366400},{"value":4396135440},{"value":6127452192},{"value":1},{"value":4371711952},{"value":16777215}],"flavor":"ARM_THREAD_STATE64","lr":{"value":8063379492},"cpsr":{"value":1073741824},"fp":{"value":6127448544},"sp":{"value":6127448512},"esr":{"value":1442840704,"description":" Address size fault"},"pc":{"value":7524698600,"matchesCrashFrame":1},"far":{"value":0}},"name":"tid_103","queue":"com.apple.main-thread","frames":[{"imageOffset":27112,"symbol":"__pthread_kill","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":67620,"symbol":"pthread_kill","symbolLocation":208,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":471172,"symbol":"__abort","symbolLocation":124,"imageIndex":2},{"imageOffset":127168,"symbol":"abort","symbolLocation":132,"imageIndex":2},{"imageOffset":29233400,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":27948312,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":27510416,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":27504740,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":27463136,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":4929516,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":28395608,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":29232364,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":27507688,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":27504740,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":27463136,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":4929516,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":5997920,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":5980964,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":6449104,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":1096596,"symbol":"__handleUncaughtException","symbolLocation":628,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":106508,"symbol":"_objc_terminate()","symbolLocation":112,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":74444,"symbol":"std::__terminate(void (*)())","symbolLocation":16,"imageIndex":6},{"imageOffset":74356,"symbol":"std::terminate()","symbolLocation":60,"imageIndex":6},{"imageOffset":410044,"symbol":"_dispatch_client_callout","symbolLocation":36,"imageIndex":7},{"imageOffset":27344,"symbol":"_dispatch_block_invoke_direct$VARIANT$mp","symbolLocation":220,"imageIndex":7},{"imageOffset":42960,"symbol":"__FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__","symbolLocation":40,"imageIndex":8},{"imageOffset":40156,"symbol":"-[FBSSerialQueue _targetQueue_performNextIfPossible]","symbolLocation":176,"imageIndex":8},{"imageOffset":56900,"symbol":"-[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource]","symbolLocation":24,"imageIndex":8},{"imageOffset":729776,"symbol":"__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__","symbolLocation":24,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":795352,"symbol":"__CFRunLoopDoSource0","symbolLocation":204,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":22136,"symbol":"__CFRunLoopDoSources0","symbolLocation":256,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":43688,"symbol":"__CFRunLoopRun","symbolLocation":768,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":122396,"symbol":"CFRunLoopRunSpecific","symbolLocation":572,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":6560,"symbol":"GSEventRunModal","symbolLocation":160,"imageIndex":9},{"imageOffset":5162496,"symbol":"-[UIApplication _run]","symbolLocation":1080,"imageIndex":10},{"imageOffset":2628360,"symbol":"UIApplicationMain","symbolLocation":2028,"imageIndex":10},{"imageOffset":6357064,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":5659504,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":735588,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":4497056,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":27583448,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":28347188,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":28372456,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":27445224,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":29268332,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":735424,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":98896,"symbol":"start","symbolLocation":444,"imageIndex":11}]},{"id":7001006,"frames":[{"imageOffset":18920,"symbol":"start_wqthread","symbolLocation":0,"imageIndex":1}]},{"id":7001037,"name":"SGen worker","frames":[{"imageOffset":5360,"symbol":"__psynch_cvwait","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":52220,"symbol":"_pthread_cond_wait$VARIANT$mp","symbolLocation":1216,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":29015296,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":25508,"symbol":"_pthread_start","symbolLocation":116,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":18940,"symbol":"thread_start","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":1}]},{"id":7001043,"name":"Finalizer","frames":[{"imageOffset":2892,"symbol":"semaphore_wait_trap","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":27961632,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":28665400,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":28665020,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":25508,"symbol":"_pthread_start","symbolLocation":116,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":18940,"symbol":"thread_start","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":1}]},{"id":7001044,"frames":[{"imageOffset":18920,"symbol":"start_wqthread","symbolLocation":0,"imageIndex":1}]},{"id":7001045,"frames":[{"imageOffset":18920,"symbol":"start_wqthread","symbolLocation":0,"imageIndex":1}]},{"id":7001046,"name":"com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread","frames":[{"imageOffset":2832,"symbol":"mach_msg_trap","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":4404,"symbol":"mach_msg","symbolLocation":72,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":27488,"symbol":"__CFRunLoopServiceMachPort","symbolLocation":368,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":44104,"symbol":"__CFRunLoopRun","symbolLocation":1184,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":122396,"symbol":"CFRunLoopRunSpecific","symbolLocation":572,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":95180,"symbol":"-[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:]","symbolLocation":232,"imageIndex":12},{"imageOffset":351292,"symbol":"-[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:]","symbolLocation":88,"imageIndex":12},{"imageOffset":4629320,"symbol":"-[UIEventFetcher threadMain]","symbolLocation":512,"imageIndex":10},{"imageOffset":407724,"symbol":"__NSThread__start__","symbolLocation":792,"imageIndex":12},{"imageOffset":25508,"symbol":"_pthread_start","symbolLocation":116,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":18940,"symbol":"thread_start","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":1}]},{"id":7001047,"queue":"com.apple.UIKit.KeyboardManagement","frames":[{"imageOffset":5876,"symbol":"__ulock_wait","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":18172,"symbol":"_dlock_wait","symbolLocation":52,"imageIndex":7},{"imageOffset":17640,"symbol":"_dispatch_thread_event_wait_slow$VARIANT$mp","symbolLocation":52,"imageIndex":7},{"imageOffset":70800,"symbol":"__DISPATCH_WAIT_FOR_QUEUE__","symbolLocation":320,"imageIndex":7},{"imageOffset":69812,"symbol":"_dispatch_sync_f_slow","symbolLocation":136,"imageIndex":7},{"imageOffset":3490008,"symbol":"__37-[_UIRemoteKeyboards startConnection]_block_invoke_3","symbolLocation":112,"imageIndex":10},{"imageOffset":133488,"symbol":"__invoking___","symbolLocation":144,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":247368,"symbol":"-[NSInvocation invoke]","symbolLocation":300,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":206832,"symbol":"__NSXPCCONNECTION_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_REPLY_BLOCK__","symbolLocation":20,"imageIndex":12},{"imageOffset":335816,"symbol":"-[NSXPCConnection _decodeAndInvokeReplyBlockWithEvent:sequence:replyInfo:]","symbolLocation":568,"imageIndex":12},{"imageOffset":190012,"symbol":"__88-[NSXPCConnection _sendInvocation:orArguments:count:methodSignature:selector:withProxy:]_block_invoke_3","symbolLocation":208,"imageIndex":12},{"imageOffset":101576,"symbol":"_xpc_connection_reply_callout","symbolLocation":60,"imageIndex":13},{"imageOffset":53252,"symbol":"_xpc_connection_call_reply_async","symbolLocation":76,"imageIndex":13},{"imageOffset":410144,"symbol":"_dispatch_client_callout3","symbolLocation":16,"imageIndex":7},{"imageOffset":118880,"symbol":"_dispatch_mach_msg_async_reply_invoke$VARIANT$mp","symbolLocation":352,"imageIndex":7},{"imageOffset":40884,"symbol":"_dispatch_lane_serial_drain$VARIANT$mp","symbolLocation":340,"imageIndex":7},{"imageOffset":43972,"symbol":"_dispatch_lane_invoke$VARIANT$mp","symbolLocation":456,"imageIndex":7},{"imageOffset":83808,"symbol":"_dispatch_workloop_worker_thread","symbolLocation":632,"imageIndex":7},{"imageOffset":20100,"symbol":"_pthread_wqthread","symbolLocation":284,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":18928,"symbol":"start_wqthread","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":1}]},{"id":7001049,"name":"tid_5703","frames":[{"imageOffset":5360,"symbol":"__psynch_cvwait","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":52220,"symbol":"_pthread_cond_wait$VARIANT$mp","symbolLocation":1216,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":29078140,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":29114340,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":28616676,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":28665400,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":28665020,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":25508,"symbol":"_pthread_start","symbolLocation":116,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":18940,"symbol":"thread_start","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":1}]},{"id":7001050,"name":"Thread Pool Worker","frames":[{"imageOffset":2916,"symbol":"semaphore_timedwait_trap","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":28618908,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":28665400,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":28665020,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":25508,"symbol":"_pthread_start","symbolLocation":116,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":18940,"symbol":"thread_start","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":1}]},{"id":7001051,"name":"Thread Pool Worker","frames":[{"imageOffset":2916,"symbol":"semaphore_timedwait_trap","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":28618908,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":28665400,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":28665020,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":25508,"symbol":"_pthread_start","symbolLocation":116,"imageIndex":1},
```

Comment: What's the question?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should always test your app on a physical device before submitting your app to the App store.

By doing so you can correct bugs or missing permissions early.

Comment: There is no way, to test without iphone?

Comment: Did you try to send invitations with TestFlight ? Or test using xCode cloud ? BTW, You have to test on real device to be sure it can start.

Comment: Thats the problem i dont have a real iPhone

Comment: find someone to help you test.  Trying to release an app for a device when you have never actually tested on that device is not a good idea.,